# Strange groovy closure construction

Tags: groovy, groovyshell, groovysh

How this code works in groovysh:

```
whatever: { x = 1+1 }
```

I dont understand how Groovy execute this closure and how interpreted this:'`\<anyText\> :`'. For calling closure used `()` or `call()` according [documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_calling_a_closure). Groovy doesnt have ':' operator.

I seen this this code in Jenkinsfile and tried to analyze it. I used groovysh, code is worked, and i dont understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a part of a bigger Groovy's map literal, with String (`whatever`) as a key, and Closure `{ x = 1+1 }` as a value. Highly likely, the brackets around the map literal `[]` are ommitted.

I can assume, that the code is evaluated in some DSL-builder, where the closure gets executed and together with the key is added in some way to the result.

`x` inside the Closure refers to a local variable either in DSL-script or in the builder.

If you look at a bigger picture, the things will start make sense very quick.

Comment: I think the same, but i dont find this map or key in variables or whatever. I was enabled intepreter DEBUG mode, but also nothing. De facto it execute Closure without call it. Magic or standard Groovy behavior?

Comment: no, in DSL-script the closure is declared, and later on it's called with either `closure.call()` or `closure()`